# How do i get Certificate Trust List on windows7 using CryptoAPI

Tags: c++, windows, certificate, cryptoapi

I want to get the CTL(Certificate Trust List)on Windows7 using Crypto API,i use the CertFindCTLInStore function,but it always return false;the GetLastError() function returns -2146885682,i don't know where i did wrong.
the code is follow:

hCertStore = CertOpenSystemStore(
        NULL,
        pszStoreName);

```
if(NULL != hCertStore)
{
    char buffer[8*1024];
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    PCCTL_CONTEXT pCTL = CertCreateCTLContext(
                         X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
                         (const BYTE*)buffer,
                         sizeof(buffer));
    CTL_FIND_USAGE_PARA usagePara;
    //first
    pCTL =  CertFindCTLInStore(
            hCertStore, 
            X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
            0,
            CTL_FIND_ANY,
            NULL,
            NULL);

    if (NULL != pCTL)
    {
        printf("Find a CTL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error Code :%d\n",GetLastError());
    }


    //Second 
    CRYPT_HASH_BLOB cryBlob;
    pCTL =  CertFindCTLInStore(
        hCertStore, 
        X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 
        0,
        CTL_FIND_SHA1_HASH,
        &cryBlob, 
        NULL);

    if (NULL != pCTL)
    {
        printf("Find a CTL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error Code :%d\n",GetLastError());
    }


    //third
    pCTL =  CertFindCTLInStore(
        hCertStore, 
        X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 
        0,
        CTL_FIND_MD5_HASH,
        &cryBlob, 
        NULL);

    if (NULL != pCTL)
    {
        printf("Find a CTL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error Code :%d\n",GetLastError());
    }

    //fourth
    CTL_FIND_USAGE_PARA ctlPara;
    pCTL =  CertFindCTLInStore(
        hCertStore, 
        X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 
        0,
        CTL_FIND_USAGE,
        &ctlPara,
        NULL);

    if (NULL != pCTL)
    {
        printf("Find a CTL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error Code :%d\n",GetLastError());
    }


    //fifth
    CTL_FIND_USAGE_PARA ctlPara2;
    pCTL =  CertFindCTLInStore(
        hCertStore, 
        X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 
        0,
        CTL_FIND_SAME_USAGE_FLAG,
        &ctlPara2, 
        NULL);

    if (NULL != pCTL)
    {
        printf("Find a CTL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error Code :%d\n",GetLastError());
    }


    //six
    CTL_CONTEXT ctlText;
    pCTL =  CertFindCTLInStore(
        hCertStore, 
        X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 
        0,
        CTL_FIND_EXISTING,
        &ctlText, 
        NULL);

    if (NULL != pCTL)
    {
        printf("Find a CTL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error Code :%d\n",GetLastError());
    }

    //seven
    CTL_FIND_SUBJECT_PARA ctlSubPara;
    pCTL =  CertFindCTLInStore(
        hCertStore, 
        X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 
        0,
        CTL_FIND_SUBJECT,
        &ctlSubPara, 
        NULL);

    if (NULL != pCTL)
    {
        printf("Find a CTL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error Code :%d\n",GetLastError());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are not getting -2146885682 but -2146885628, aka 0x80092004 aka `CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND`. Quite simply, there are no CTLs in the store.

Comment: yep,you said right,do you have any simple that this function call successfully.i just don't understand why MSDN do't give a simple example use this function.they just give a simple example said that change Certificate to CRL,i just don't find an example that can work

Comment: Your code works, and successfully reports that there are no CTLs in the store. What makes you believe there should be some? If you want to get the certificates of all the trusted root CAs, use `CertOpenSystemStore` to open ROOT store, then `CertFindCertificateInStore` to enumerate certs.

Comment: I do things like what you said,and it works well.we enum all stores in the system,and select the trust stores.maybe i just need to find another way to solve the problem.